# java reflect method.invoke is not working

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to invoke a function using Method. The thing is the below code is not executing. I tried searching and it all ended the same. Can someone throw some light why it is not working? I had tried putting some log and it all reached until method.invoke function. There has been no exception thrown for the below code.

```
public String customSearchedParams() throws Exception
    {
            Class<?> dynamicObj = Class.forName(this.className);
            Constructor<?> constructor = dynamicObj.getConstructor(long.class, long.class, long.class, long.class);
            Object obj = constructor.newInstance(this.startTime, this.time, this.t1, this.t2);                
            Method method = dynamicObj.getMethod("getCustomSearch", new Class[]{long.class, long.class, long.class, long.class, long.class});
            this.data = (String) method.invoke(obj, new Object[]{this.startTime, this.time, this.t1, this.t2, this.paramIDs});
            return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

Constructor:

```
public Traffic(long startTime, long endTime, long t1, long t2){
     // Assign to local variables
}
```

getCustomSearch:

```
public String getCustomSearch(long startTime, long endTime, long t1, long t2, long paramIDs) throws Exception {
   // do DB calls --> return JSONArray as String
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "Is not executing" isn't a problem description we can help with much. Are there exceptions?

Comment: have updated the question. No exception has been thrown

Comment: if No exception has been thrown - what is not working? what do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Post more code of this class please, such as  the `constructor` and `getCustomSearch`

Comment: method.invoke is expected to return a string. but its not. After that, it returns 500 to the browser.

Comment: What does `method.invoke()` return? Or doesn't it reach the point where the method returns? To check that, temporarily replace the `getCustomSearch()` method body with a `return "HELLO";` statement to make sure it's not the method's implementation.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Tried that method, didnt work. It seems it doesn't reach the getCustomSearch() function itself

Comment: Learn to use your IDE's debugger. Put a breakpoint on the getCustomSearch() method. Then you'll KNOW if it reaches the method or not. Also single-stepping through your customSearchedParams() might be helpful.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff As I mentioned in the question itself, i tried using logger step by step and the log didn't come after method.invoke()

Comment: Logging is poor man's debugging... I was talking about your IDE's debugging features.

Comment: IDE didn't show any errors. If shown, why would I come here in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Class.getMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) receives a variable length arguments.  You should pass the classes as individual arguments instead of casting into array.  Same with the `invoke()`

```
        Method method = dynamicObj.getMethod("getCustomSearch", long.class, long.class, long.class, long.class, long.class);
        this.data = (String) method.invoke(obj, this.startTime, this.time, this.t1, this.t2, this.paramIDs);
```

Comment: Tried this thing too.. Unfortunately, the result is the same (didnt work)

Comment: first of all, this is the correct way to use `getMethod` and `invoke`. second, please post the declaration of `getCustomSearch` method

Comment: I have this getCustomSearch in another class called Traffic. I have passed the class name as pkg name and Class name.

Comment: once again, please post the declaration of `getCustomSearch` method in `Traffic` class

Comment: sorry I don't understand.. I have posted it in question I think.. If not please correct me

Comment: well, it seems that the declaration matches the reflection.  usually, a 500 response does mean an exception. if not, what does the return value `this.data` contain?

Comment: To the front, if an 500 response is sent means, this.data would be null right. Also I have this doubt, since both the classes are in separate packages, should I add import of traffic class where I use method.invoke?

Comment: Ok.. Then where am I going wrong? Suggested by Ralph in comments I tried returning some string by default in getcustomsearch method. It didn't return the default string which I have assigned.

Comment: I would do the following : 1) add a `System.out.println("something")` as first statement inside the `getCustomSearch` method. 2) add `System.out.println("after")` after the call to the `invoke` before the `return "SUCCESS";` 3) add in the `customSearchedParams` a try catch block with `e.printStackTrace()` to be sure there isn't an exception that gets lost

Comment: but all these steps are just regular debug measures that you can think of yourself....

Comment: Have tried steps 1 and 2 earlier. Will try step 3 and update here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me. The code that I have posted is working and I have declared paramIDs as String and I'm trying to pass it as long. Thats why method.invoke is not executing.